Restricting Microsoft Identity authentication to only approved devices
I am using Microsoft Identity in an Azure hosted web app and want to restrict authentication to only whitelisted devices that have been issued from our company.  Is there any device identifiers sent in the validation request that I could use to compare it to a whitelist? I can't use an IP address whitelist as we want access to only be granted when requested from an approved device.
I can see through the Graph API, I can get a list of registered devices. Is it possible to use information from there along with information passed inside the AudienceValidator section of the AddAuthentication configuration?
